# No such module 'MyFramework'

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am trying to create cocoa touch framework 
this its podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.platform = :ios
s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'
s.name = "MyFramework"
s.summary = "My first framework."
s.requires_arc = true
s.version = "1.0.8"
s.license = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE" }
s.authors = { "....." => '...' }
s.homepage = "https://github.com/......"
s.source = { :git => "https://github.com/.......", :tag => "#{s.version}"}
s.dependency 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
s.source_files = 'MyFramework/**/*.{h,m}'
s.resources = "MyFramework/**/*"

end
```

but when i use it in another project pod file :

```
 source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
 source '[MyFramework URL]'
 target 'new project' do
 use_frameworks!
  pod 'MyFramework'
 end
```

i get that error " No such module 'MyFramework' " when trying to import it

Comment: What is '[MyFramework URL]'? If you examine the git repo there, do you see MyFramework?

Comment: [MyFramework URL] is the git link to the framework and yes the framework exists in the repo